# $.each not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following code:

```
$.getJSON("updatechat.php", messageSender, function(data) {

            var tmp = -1;
            $.each(data, function(index, message) {
                if (lastID != -1) {
                    $("#mainBox").append("<div>" 
                                  + message.time +
                                  "<span>&nbsp;" + message.sender + "&nbsp;: </span>" + 
                                  message.message + 
                                  "</div>");
                }
                tmp = message.id;
            });
            lastID = tmp;
        });
```

My problem is that sometimes, for a strange reason, the $.each() function is not ran, wich causes lastID to change it's value to -1 (the value of tmp). In updatechat.php i have a query that selects the last ID. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I found out that at odd calls of $.getJSON it enters $.each and at even calls it does not.

Comment: show `data` by doing `console.log(data);return false;` in your code before var tmp = -1; and put here. in your code. then only anyone can help you.thanks.After writing this code check your console and see what data you are getting.

Comment: Hmm, sometimes the data is -1 and sometimes it is the JSON array it is supposed to be. @anantkumarsingh

Comment: show that if possible?

Comment: The each always works, it's just that sometimes you give it something it can't iterate over. Likely an issue not related to the code you provided.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, I've just noticed that sometimes the data (int getJSON) is NULL. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe because there aren't any new messages? if data is null, you should do nothing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/fDKmgz5 Here is the log output

Comment: yea, that makes sense. because first call sets it to the last id, second call tries to get messages since that last id, finds none, and last id is reset to -1, and the process repeats.

Comment: @KevinB even if there are no new messages, I have to get the JSON data (the sender, message, time, id). If i don't, this will screw up lastID, which leads to other problems.

Comment: but... your server isn't returning that information, it's returning null.

Comment: Exactly, can't figure out why...

Comment: you won't figure it out by asking here and not providing your server code...

Comment: How are you using lastid? I assume you are passing it in with each request for new messages.

Comment: At the end of the each function tmp should contain the lastID. After that I change lastID to the new lastID, which is tmp now.

Comment: ` <?php

    
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "handrei", "toporasi", "chat");

    $sender = $_GET['sender'];
    $lastID = $_GET['lastID'];

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT id, message, sender, time FROM messages WHERE sender != '".$sender."' AND id > ".$lastID;

    $result = $connection -> query($sqlQuery);

    $rowsForJSON = array();
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) { 
        $rowsForJSON[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($rowsForJSON);

?>`

Comment: Exactly what i expected. see my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first request, you get an array of messages and set the last id to the last id in the array of messages. On the next call, you get null because there are no new messages since that last id, so there's nothing to iterate over, and the last id get reset to -1, and the process repeats.

You should just not do anything if `data` is `null`. Once there are new messages, `data` will no longer be `null` and the `$.each` will run, appending any new messages to the message box.

```
if (!data) { return; }
var tmp = -1;
$.each(data, ...
```

with this change, the first run will find messages, `data` will not be `null`, and the messages will be appended. On second run, 5 seconds later, no new messages, data is `null`, and the `$.each` is skipped leaving `lastid` at it's current value.

Comment: Well i found a workaround: if (tmp != -1) lastID = tmp; but i wanted to figure out why this happens. Also, your code is not good for my situation since this function is called every 5seconds, so the user will wait 10 sec instead.

Comment: How does my solution make them wait 5 more seconds than yours? all i'm suggesting is adding 1 line that prevents `lastid` from being set back to -1, it should then stay at the correct last id until a new messages are found.

Comment: Because you exit the function prematurely, the #("mainbox").append will not be called, so this call will not display anything. With my workaround, the lastID will keep its value.

Comment: basically, our solutions are identical in result, the only difference is mine avoids calling $.each when there aren't any messages to append, yours calls $.each anyway and then prevents it from doing damage.

Comment: if `data` is null, the `$.each` isn't going to append anything anyway, why let it run.

Comment: Oh you are right, i misunderstood. But still, why is the data null? It should always return something.

Comment: Your php only looks for messages that are newer than the last id. If none are found, it returns null. This is a good thing, as it reduces bandwidth used. No sense in returning all messages every time.

Comment: Oh god, how could i be so blind... Thank you for your time, i think I should go to sleep :)

Comment: Beware, i think your sql code is open to sql injection.

Comment: Yeah I know, this code is just for testing purposes.